# Start VBA macro (Excel) from commandline

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA macro in Excel, which generates some C-code.
Is is it possible to trigger the execution of this macro as part of the make-based build process (e.g. via VBScript)?
If yes, how?

Comment: Sounds like and interesting convolved way of doing things :). Could you post why are you using it this way? Just curiosity ...

Comment: The Excel code generator was not my idea. The generated code is a configuration for an communication component for an embedded system. In this way the colleagues can modify the configuration, without being familiar with the implementation. Excel provides a sufficient UI for this. In addition the generator can perform some sanity checks and ensure both endpoints have the corresponding configuration.

Comment: Tnx for the answer! I saw similar implementations before, but all of them exported numerical results to csv, post-processed by awk or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to automate Excel and then you use the `InvokeMember` function to run your macro.

The following article shows you how to do it from .Net, it should be similar to call from VBscript except that you'll need to use late binding: [HOW TO: Run Office Macros by Using Automation from Visual C# .NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20150120043908/http://support.microsoft.com:80/kb/306683)

And here's a blog post showing how to call a custom macro in Outlook from VBScript: [Calling Outlook VBA Macro from outside (VB/VBScript/C#)](https://web.archive.org/web/20130528074109/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/sachinsancheti/archive/2006/05/16/598951.aspx)

Comment: Thanx. This was what I needed. (The HOWTO article linked to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177760/EN-US/, where the 'app.Run "Module1.TestMacro" ' is mentioned